# Why isn't my program reading the next line of the file?

Tags: python

I have a problem. I am trying to see how many characters and words are in a file, but I have three bugs.
Code:

```py
file = "file.test"
f=open(file, 'r')
numberWords = 0
chars = 0
chars_lst = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e', 
  'f',
  'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k','l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
  'A','B','C','D','E', 'F','G', 'H','I','J','K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,'~', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '{'
, '}', '|', ':', '<', '>', '?', '`', '[', ']', '\\', ';', '\'', '"', ',', '>', '/'

]

for line in f:
  for i in line:
    if i == " " or i == '\n' or i == '\t':
      numberWords += 1
      f.readline()

    if i in chars_lst:
      chars += 1
      f.readline()

f.close()

print(chars, numberWords)
```

#### Bug 1

Bug number one is that when I put a space, it is supposed to read the `spaces`but it didn't, how could I fix this? As you can see, I tried adding the `.readline()` but it still didn't work

#### Bug 2

Its not reading multiple lines in a file. I tried adding the `\n` to be readable but that didn't fix it, and now I just don't know what to do.

#### Bug 3

Every time I run the program, I get the following output:
`8 0`

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your main problem appears to be here

```
for line in file:
```

it should be

```
for line in f:
```

because `f` is your handle from `f=open(file, 'r')`, and `file` is just a string `'file.test'`

Comment: @elipie did it help? You should also get rid of  `f.readline()` as it shouldn't really be there

Comment: yes it did, now how would I be able to read *multiple* lines?

Comment: @elipie your code is already (should be) reading multiple lines. `for line in f:` is a loop over all lines in your file

Comment: hmm, when I input in the file: 
```
H
i
``` - supposed to be multiple lines by the way
The output says:
1  1

Answer (score 0):

`.readline` only reads the first line, or whatever line you tell it to read, however, `.readlines` will read all the lines in a file. I believe if you tried using `.readlines` instead of `.readline`, the issue should be fixed.

Comment: where would I put the `.readlines`?  I tried putting it where the start of the first for loop, but it didn't work. Lemme try in other places

Comment: It should be put before you start testing for letters

Comment: @elipie You should not be mixing two things. either you use `for line in f:` construct or `f.readline`, do not use both at the same time

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that your nested for loops aren't iterating over the file handler you created (`f`), but the string `file`.

This results in you looping over the characters `'f', 'i', 'l', 'e', '.', 't', 'e', 's', 't'` instead of looping over every line in your file and then every character in each line. The reason that this doesn't crash your inner loop is that in Python single character string is still an itterable, so you can still loop over it. Your code then counts 8 text characters, and 0 whitespace characters in "file.test" which is why you get a result of (8, 0) displayed regardless of the contents of the file.

If you change to iterate over the file handler instead of the filename. You'll be much closer to your desired behavior.

```py
for line in f:
    for i in line:
        # Do things here.
```

Both `readline()`, and `readlines()` return what they read from the file, unless you capture this output, (normally by assigning it to a variable), Python will discard the returned value without complaint.